# Get value form multiple values in json

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to one value from multiple values in json field. I'm using this for loop to get data form json file:

```
for i in data['issues']:
x = [i]
for j in x:
    pprint(j['fields']['assignee'])
```

And this return me this value:

```
{'active': True,
 'avatarUrls': {'16x16': 'link',
                '24x24': 'link',
                '32x32': 'link',
                '48x48': 'link'},
 'displayName': 'First name, Last name',
 'emailAddress': 'name.namek@mail.com',
 'name': 'Name',
 'self': 'link'}
```

I'm trying to get one of this values using, for example i want to get value of 'displayName'

```
pprint(j['fields']['assignee'][0])
```

but in python IDE I'am getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Ok to be more specific I want to get for example value displayName from this json, maybe it will be easier for you if I paste here a whole json structure

```
{
"expand": "schema,names",
"startAt": 0,
"maxResults": 50,
"total": 4,
"issues": [
    {
        "expand": "editmeta,renderedFields,transitions,changelog,operations",
        "id": "682884",
        "self": "https://jira.sabre.com/rest/api/2/issue/682884",
        "key": "ENG-664",
        "fields": {
            "data": "data",
            "assignee": {
                "self": "link",
                "name": "First name Last name",
                "emailAddress": "ame.namek@mail.com",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "16x16": "link",
                    "24x24": "link",
                    "32x32": "link",
                    "48x48": "link"
                },
                "displayName": "First name Last name",
                "active": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "expand": "editmeta,renderedFields,transitions,changelog,operations",
        "id": "682884",
        "self": "https://jira.sabre.com/rest/api/2/issue/682884",
        "key": "ENG-664",
        "fields": {
            "data": "data",
            "assignee": {
                "self": "link",
                "name": "First name Last name",
                "emailAddress": "ame.namek@mail.com",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "16x16": "link",
                    "24x24": "link",
                    "32x32": "link",
                    "48x48": "link"
                },
                "displayName": "First name Last name",
                "active": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "expand": "editmeta,renderedFields,transitions,changelog,operations",
        "id": "682884",
        "self": "https://jira.sabre.com/rest/api/2/issue/682884",
        "key": "ENG-664",
        "fields": {
            "data": "data",
            "assignee": {
                "self": "link",
                "name": "First name Last name",
                "emailAddress": "ame.namek@mail.com",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "16x16": "link",
                    "24x24": "link",
                    "32x32": "link",
                    "48x48": "link"
                },
                "displayName": "First name Last name",
                "active": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "expand": "editmeta,renderedFields,transitions,changelog,operations",
        "id": "682884",
        "self": "https://jira.sabre.com/rest/api/2/issue/682884",
        "key": "ENG-664",
        "fields": {
            "data": "data",
            "assignee": {
                "self": "link",
                "name": "First name Last name",
                "emailAddress": "ame.namek@mail.com",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "16x16": "link",
                    "24x24": "link",
                    "32x32": "link",
                    "48x48": "link"
                },
                "displayName": "First name Last name",
                "active": true
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: Try `pprint(j['fields']['assignee']['displayName'])`

Comment: I already try this :) still get
pprint(j['fields']['assignee']['displayName'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Alex's code should work on the `dict` from your question. If it's not then please clarify your question. You can start by fixing the indentation of your code as it currently doesn't execute.

Comment: Please see above. Is this will be helpful ?

Comment: Your input is not valid JSON. Check it at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Now its valid, sorry :)

Comment: Alex' code works for the json you provided

Comment: Ah true, but when i apply Alex code to my whole json file generated by application api, i get this error again, here is a whole json file, I only change the values for security purpose ;)
http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/qUFyV0WE1y